# Associating two rails models in a react component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have two models, Company and Establishment, and I need to show the company an establishment belongs to in a react view. I am able to show the name and address of an establishment but not the company it belongs to. When I try to list `companyName` I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: company is not defined` error. How can I reference the Company model so I can list the company an establishment belongs to? I have already called the company model I just need to filter by the company an establishment belongs to. Below is my code...

```
render: function () {
    var establishments = this.state.establishments.map(function (establishment, index) {
      var panelType = 'good';

      if (establishment.highest_incidence_priority > 0) {
        panelType = 'bad';
      }

      return (
        <Panel companyID={ company.id } companyName={ company.name } establishmentID={ establishment.id } key={ index } priority={ establishment.highest_incidence_priority } name={ establishment.name } address={ establishment.address} type={ panelType } />
      );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <section>
        { establishments }
      </section>
    );
  }
```

Comment: youre not defining `company` in the map. you may be looking for `establishment.company`. can you show us what establishment looks like within that map function and what the state of the component is?

Comment: Thanks but I realized it was simpler to just use jbuilder

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using jbuilder to associate the two models, creating a view and then calling the information I needed. Much simpler than modifying the React code